# What model is used to provide translation for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, translation

Which is the best model to provide iPhone apps in multi-languages?

1. Add a button inside the app that allow the user to translate the app (so, the app lang will be independent from the iPhone lang).
2. Allow the app to read the system lang (and the app cannot change it). so to change the lang for the app, one should go to change the lang of the system.

**EDIT**

1. In all cases, my app will detect user's lang and use it on first install, I am asking about subsequent uses.
2. I don't ask about how to do, I just need to know what is should fit better.

Thanks.

Comment: 2. Because 99.9% of all users want the language that is configured in their phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with 2, because it simplifies the user experience. Why make the user do extra work or clutter up your UI, when you already know the language that they've set their device to?

Apple is all about simple user interfaces and removing unneeded options, or minimally default to the most logical ones.

If you want to give your users additional options, then use the language set on the device when you initially launch the app, but allow the user to change the language in the options. This is for scenarios such as, the user's native language is Chinese, but you don't have Chinese, so you default to English. Well, the user maybe doesn't speak English but speaks French, so they'll choose French.

That way, the user can continue to use your app without having to constantly switch their device settings between French and Chinese.

Comment: I already implemented #1 in the app (still in dev), and I am thinking of #2, but as my `edit` say, On first startup, the lang will be detected. So the best answer is to "Pick user default lang on first install, then allow him (from inside the app) to choose the new lang that he needs to override the defaults" .. What do you think?

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy, Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You generally set up localized strings for everything, and it will use the users system language. For a tutorial on how to do this see: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use iPhone's language.

If you are trying to localize your app (I mean give multiple language support) it is best to use localizable strings. The key is separating texts from app.

iOS will take care of which language text to use based on the iPhone settings. A good stating point should be http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial